# Is it possible to avoid tearing apart from a blackhole if moving fast enough?

Tags: physics, gravity, black-hole

I have a spacecraft zooming directly into a blackhole with constant thrust.
Considering the gravitational force of that blackhole and that there is no terminal velocity to slow me down.

According [a study](https://www.space.com/41923-black-hole-material-one-third-light-speed.html), particles are pulled at a speed of 56K miles/s into a blackhole.

Theoretically, if my spacecraft moves fast enough (56K mi/s +1) will it overtake the force applied by that black hole and prevent it tearing its subatomic particles, keeping my spaceship intact?

Comment: This has more to do with physics than space exploration.

Comment: The astronaut would not survive to be so close to a blackhole. He would be torn apart by the gravity of the black hole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Acceleration due to gravity is independent of speed**

The acceleration a spaceship experiences depends only on the mass of the black hole and the distance to it.

**High acceleration does not by itself hurt you**

What matters is the *differential* force (Tidal force), how much more (or less!) gravity pulls on one part of the ship than other parts.
If one part of the ship is accelerated at 100,000,000G, and another part at 100,000,150G, there is a differential acceleration of 150G which the structure of the ship has to withstand to not be torn apart. If on the other hand all parts of the ship are accelerated at 100,000,000G the structure experiences no mechanical stress of any sort.

So why do black holes tear things apart then?

This comes down to the fact that objects have physical size. The front of your spacecraft is slightly closer to the black hole than the back, and they therefore experience different acceleration due to gravity. At normal levels of gravity, the difference of your feet being closer to the Earth than your head is such a minor difference that it doesn't matter.
But when the mass gets cranked up to extreme levels, and the distances short, this differential force gets increasingly important.

$$F_{tidal} \propto d^{-3}$$

These tidal forces are inversely proportional to distance cubed, so the only thing that matters is how close you are to the black hole, not how fast you are going.

Comment: So the tidal force is proportional to the gradient of the gravitational field ?  What are the units of gravitational gradient? m/sec^2/m ? Does that make sec^-2? This actually came up in Christmas dinner conversation with my nephew the physics major.

Comment: @Woody Yes, that's exactly right.

Comment: Speed might actually be helpful--it could reduce your exposure to damaging tides and thus in some situations make an encounter survivable that would not be so at lower speed.  Humans can survive peak accelerations higher than they can survive sustained accelerations and tides are pretty much the same on the body.

Answer (score 2):

It’s the tidal forces that will get your ship... or your body. Spaceships can be made a lot stronger than human bodies.

The hydrodynamic forces in your cardiovascular system are a particular problem. The arterial blood pressure at any point in your body is the sum of pumping pressure of the heart plus the hydrostatic pressure from gravity.

For instance, your arterial pressure is 120mmHg at the heart. Let’s do this in cm of water (cmH20) to make the arithmetic easier. Call your BP 165cmH2O at your heart. That becomes 300cmH2O at your feet and 125cmH2O at the top of your head. This assumes you are in a uniform 1-g gravity field.

If you are in the ISS in microgravity, BP is 165cmH2O everywhere in your body.

Now imagine you are weightless in a 1-g/meter gravity gradient. Your belly button is about your center of mass. The top of your head is at -1-g and your feet are at +1-g. Now your blood pressure is 190 at your heart, 165 at your feet and 235 at your head.

If you get a bit closer to the black hole, the gradient doubles to 2-g/m. Pressure in head arteries is up to 470. Keep going, and something is going to pop.

Except things are even worse in your veins.  The heart has no “suction head”. Your heart can’t pump blood unless the big veins supplying it have blood in them. In regular uniform gravity fields, blood runs downhill from the head to the heart. And, if you are hanging upside down, blood runs downhill from your feet to your heart. In the special case of zero-g, tissue pressure is high enough to return blood to the heart.

But in a gravity gradient, every direction is downhill away from your center of mass, which is quite close to your heart. In this way, gravity gradient tolerance is very similar to spin tolerance. Humans usually pass out in a 6rpm flat spin within a few seconds. https://books.google.ca/books

Larry Niven dodged this problem by immersing characters in a flotation tank. This would increase the tolerance for gravity gradients, but not eliminate it. Different tissues have different densities so if the gradient is high enough, you still get torn to pieces.

Bottom line: stay well clear of black holes. Don't take a giraffe as a mascot. But you will pass out before you get ripped to bits so it won’t be too painful.